# django dateTimeField deltat

Tags: django, time, delta

I would like know the delta between the creation of a model row and now.
For the moment I have:

```
 from datetime import date, time, datetime
from django.utils import timezone
before= self.begin_current_player#models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
before= datetime(before.year, before.month, before.day, before.hour, before.minute,before.second)
now_date= datetime.now()
delta_seconde = int((before-now_date).seconds)
```

But the result is very strange(sometime >0 , sometime <0,sometime error type error).
Do you have a idea ? 
thx

Comment: I don't understand that second definition of `before`. You already have the value of the field, why define it again from the individual components? You will just end up with the same value.

Comment: But in order to understand your question, you will need to show some sample values and their results.

Comment: The second definition of before i's juste fir have a datetime format. In django what is the way for get the number of seconde between a DateTimeField type and now ?

Comment: But `self.begin_current_player` is already a `datetime` object. Anyway use `total_seconds` atrribute of a `timedelta` object to get the total number of seconds.